# I want to redirect requests to domain A to a sub folder of domain B in vhosts config

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an issue that I'm having some problems with:

I need to redirect all requests to **http://domainA.com** to **http://domainB.com/somefolder/**

It's my understanding that a site has been built there, but they need the requests to come in from http://domainA.com

I understand rewriting the domain to do like for like, for example, http://domainA.com/blog/index.php to http://domainB.com/blog/index.php

Can I get some pointers on how to achieve rewriting the URL, and adding in the new path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a reverse proxy here.

In your domainA config, you can do

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName domainA.com

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://domainB.com/somefolder
   ProxyPassReverse / http://domainB.com/somefolder

</VirtualHost>
```

You'll take all requests to domainA and pass them to domainB, the `ProxyPreserveHost` directive will ensure all requests arriving at domainB appear to have come to domainA. To the end user, it will look like they are only browsing domainA, even though the content is being served by domainB.

You need to make sure the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are enabled for this to work.

Comment: If I used a reverse proxy here, does that mean that the webserver is then effectively hosting the connection for the user?

Comment: Technically both webservers are; each request would open two connections, from the browser to domainA and then from domainA to domainB. You could say domainA is handling requests on behalf of domainB.